# Module inclusion in ruby eigen class

Tags: ruby, class, module, metaprogramming

In my point of view, For instance_eval, the class scope becomes the singleton class also know as eigenclass of the target object. So Instance methods created on the singleton class for an object become singleton methods for that object. I mean the following two code snippets produces expected results

```
class TestClass; end
```

**Using eigen class**

```
class TestClass
  class << self   
    def class_method
      "class_method of TestClass"
    end
  end
end
```

**Using instance_eval**

```
TestClass.instance_eval do
 def class_method2
   "class_method of TestClass"
 end
end
```

So we can call TestClass.class_method and TestClass.class_method2 and get the corresponding results.
Now let's assume we have a module TestModule

```
module TestModule
  def instance_method
    " instance_method from TestModule"
  end
end
```

Now if we include this module in the eigen class then we can access the instance_method as a class method of the TestClass

```
class TestClass
  class << self   
    include TestModule
  end
end
```

So TestClass.instance_method will works as expected.

But if we do the same thing using instance_eval it fails.Please check the following snippet

```
TestClass.instance_eval do
  include TestModule
end
```

When I tried to call TestClass.instance_method then I am getting the following error.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)
```

Would anybody explain what is the issue and what is the internal logic behind this. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You can use `instance_eval` with `extend` to bring in the class method: `TestClass.instance_eval do; extend TestModule; end`, but that's no different than just `TestClass.extend TestModule`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because if you use `include`, it doesn't matter what a *current class* is, but what does `self` point to (`include` is a method called on `self` if you don't specify explicit receiver), and in your example, `self` points to `TestClass`, so `TestModule#instance_method` becomes instance method of `TestClass`, like in following example:

```
class TestClass
end

module TestModule
  def test_method
    'test'
  end
end
TestClass.instance_eval { include TestModule }
TestClass.new.test_method
# => "test"
```